# WriteFileGather - append buffers to file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, writefile

Using Windows API's `WriteFileGather`, I am writing a file to the disk.
I want to append new buffers to the existing file.
What is the way to prevent `WriteFileGather` from overwriting the existing file?

Answer (score 2):

`WriteFileGather` will never overwrite the file unless you ask it to - theres no implied overwrite/append option, theres ONLY a 'please write data at file position X option'.

You should open the file handle normally (making sure you've got `GENERIC_WRITE` access and specifying flags at least flags `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` by using `CreateFile`

Then you set the position the file writes at by using the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members of the `OVERLAPPED` you pass in as the 5th parameter.

This is similar to the way `WriteFile` works when its running in asynchronous mode - you *must* specify the position to write at. Its probably easier to learn how to do positional asyncronous writes using `WriteFile` first then move onto `WriteFileGather` if you need its additional power.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for docs.

EDIT: To answer the comment from Harry, to get the end of file you can either remember how much you've written before (assuming this is a new file you created) or get the current file size from a HANDLE using SetFilePointerEx with distance 0 and method FILE_END which will return to you the end of the file. There are other ways of getting a file size but beware you may get a cached answer (e.g. if iterating over a directory) and so the above is recommended.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: It will never overwrite the existing file as the question asked/implied. It may overwrite valid contents of the file _if you ask it to via setting the offset to data which already exists_

Comment: @Harry Johnston - editted first paragraph to be clear